# Responsive Background

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, background-image

I am trying to make a background image of the particles JS responsible. Thus I used this code:

```
#particles-js {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width:100% ;
height: 100%;
background-image: image-url("rub.jpg");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
-webkit-background-size:cover;
-moz-background-size:cover;
-o-background-size:cover;
background-size:cover;
}
```

but when I resize my browser I get this result:

[image: web page resized]

Which in my opinion is too small in height. I used the image `background-size: cover` because it is what is recommended to make the background image responsive but it does not fit well.

My question is if it depends on the original size of the image or I am doing something wrong? and if there is any specific way to make the background really responsive? In other words to make the image background fit the maximum height and width of the screen of the the different mobile devices?

Comment: Please include a working fiddle.

Comment: try adding `html,body {height:100%;}`

Comment: I thied with body: 100% but the same happened

Comment: I am using the ruby on rails framework with Jquery

Comment: We'll need to see the rest of your html.  You are correct in using `background-size:cover`, which leads me to believe that the container that's containing your `#particles-js` is mis-shaped.

Comment: This is the rest of my HTML code

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Rubiksolutions</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
<div>
 <nav>
 <div class="cube"></div>
  <div id="nav_wrapper">
  <ul>

Comment: <li><%=image_tag("name.jpg", :size => "150x40")%></li>
   <li><a>Inicio</a></li>
      <li class="submenu"><a>Productos</a>
       <ul class="drop-menu menu-1">
         <li>una</li>
         <li>dos</li>
         <li>tres</li>
         <li>cuatro</li>
         <li>cinco</li>
         <li>seis</li>
       </ul>
      </li>

Comment: <li class="submenu"><a>Servicios</a>
       <ul class="drop-menu menu-2">
         <li>una</li>
         <li>dos</li>
         <li>tres</li>
         <li>cuatro</li>
         <li>cinco</li>
         <li>seis</li>
       </ul>
      </li>

Comment: I will make a new question better with all my code

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps: http://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/ggMYBQ

The key detail is to apply the background image to an element that covers the full height of the screen, eg html

CSS

```
html{ 
  background:url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1440804518589-c0bbe09a8103) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Hi, the problem is that the background is not part of the body or the html element is part of the particles Js div. Here is my complete question and code. Sorry for not posting it entirely.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41621559/responsive-background-image-with-particle-js