# Responsive Background image with particle js

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, responsive-design, background-image

I am using the floowing code:

application.html.erb file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Rubiksolutions</title>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<nav>
<div class="cube"></div>
    <div id="nav_wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li><%=image_tag("name.jpg", :size => "150x40")%></li>
        <li><a>Inicio</a></li>
        <li class="submenu"><a>Productos</a>
            <ul class="drop-menu menu-1">
                 <li>una</li>
                 <li>dos</li>
                 <li>tres</li>
                 <li>cuatro</li>
                 <li>cinco</li>
                 <li>seis</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="submenu"><a>Servicios</a>
            <ul class="drop-menu menu-2">
                 <li>una</li>
                 <li>dos</li>
                 <li>tres</li>
                 <li>cuatro</li>
                 <li>cinco</li>
                 <li>seis</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="submenu"><a>Educación</a>
            <ul class="drop-menu menu-3">
                 <li>una</li>
                 <li>dos</li>
                 <li>tres</li>
                 <li>cuatro</li>
                 <li>cinco</li>
                 <li>seis</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a>Contáctanos</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="container" id="btn-menu" onclick="myFunction(this)">
        <div class="bar1"></div>
        <div class="bar2"></div>
        <div class="bar3"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="logo-image">
    <%=image_tag("name.jpg", :size => "150x40")%>
    </div>
</nav>
</div>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my home.html.erb file:

```
<section>
<div id="particles-js"></div>
</section>
<div class="bender" id="bender2">
<div class="head">
<div class="antenna">
  <div class="antenna-circle"></div>   
  <div class="antenna-triangle"></div>
  <div class="antenna-base"></div>
</div>  
<div class="eyes">
  <div class="curve--left"></div>
  <div class="curve--right"></div>
  <div class="eyes-subcontainer">        
    <div class="eye eye--left">
      <div class="pupil"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="eye eye--right">
      <div class="pupil"></div>
    </div>        
  </div>
</div>
<div class="mouth">
  <ul class="tooth--vertical">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
  <span class="tooth--horizontal tooth-horizontal1"></span>
  <span class="tooth--horizontal tooth--horizontal2"></span>     
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is my main.Js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 console.log("Loading particles.js");

 particlesJS('particles-js',
  {
  "particles": {
    "number": {
      "value": 80,
      "density": {
        "enable": true,
        "value_area": 800
      }
    },
    "color": {
      "value": "#ffffff"
    },
    "shape": {
      "type": "circle",
      "stroke": {
        "width": 0,
        "color": "#000000"
      },
      "polygon": {
        "nb_sides": 5
      },
      "image": {
        "src": "img/github.svg",
        "width": 100,
        "height": 100
      }
    },
    "opacity": {
      "value": 0.5,
      "random": false,
      "anim": {
        "enable": false,
        "speed": 1,
        "opacity_min": 0.1,
        "sync": false
      }
    },
    "size": {
      "value": 5,
      "random": true,
      "anim": {
        "enable": false,
        "speed": 40,
        "size_min": 0.1,
        "sync": false
      }
    },
    "line_linked": {
      "enable": true,
      "distance": 150,
      "color": "#ffffff",
      "opacity": 0.4,
      "width": 1
    },
    "move": {
      "enable": true,
      "speed": 6,
      "direction": "none",
      "random": false,
      "straight": false,
      "out_mode": "out",
      "attract": {
        "enable": false,
        "rotateX": 600,
        "rotateY": 1200
      }
    }
  },
  "interactivity": {
    "detect_on": "canvas",
    "events": {
      "onhover": {
        "enable": true,
        "mode": "repulse"
      },
      "onclick": {
        "enable": true,
        "mode": "push"
      },
      "onresize": {
        "enable": true,
        "density_auto": true,
        "density_area": 400 // nb_particles = particles.nb * (canvas width *  canvas height / 1000) / density_area
    }
    },
    "modes": {
      "grab": {
        "distance": 400,
        "line_linked": {
          "opacity": 1
        }
      },
      "bubble": {
        "distance": 400,
        "size": 40,
        "duration": 2,
        "opacity": 8,
        "speed": 3
      },
      "repulse": {
        "distance": 200
      },
      "push": {
        "particles_nb": 4
      },
      "remove": {
        "particles_nb": 2
      }
    }
    },
    "retina_detect": true,
    "config_demo": {
    "hide_card": false,
    "background_color": "#b61924",
    "background_image": "",
    "background_position": "50% 50%",
    "background_repeat": "no-repeat",
    "background_size": "cover"
   }
   }
   );
   });
var state= false;
$(function(){
$(".cube")
    .cube({size:{width:50,height:50}})
    .execute("x (R' U R') D2 (R U' R') D2 (R U R') D2 (R U' R') D2 (R U R') D2 (R U' R') D2 R2 x'");
});
function myFunction(x) {
x.classList.toggle("change");
if (!state){
  $("#nav_wrapper").css('transform', 'translateX(0%)');
  state = true;
}
else{
  $("#nav_wrapper").css('transform', 'translateX(-150%)'); 
  state = false;
}
};
```

This is part of my CSS file:

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#particles-js {
  display:block;
  vertical-align:bottom;
  -webkit-transform:scale(1);
  -ms-transform:scale(1);
  transform:scale(1);
  opacity:1;
  -webkit-transition:opacity .8s ease,-webkit-transform 1.4s ease;
  transition:opacity .8s ease, transform 1.4s ease;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background-image: image-url("rub.jpg");
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size:cover;
  -moz-background-size:cover;
  -o-background-size:cover;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:cover;
 }

nav {
  position:fixed;
  left:50%;top:0;
  z-index: 9999;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-left:-40%; /* negative margin equal to half the width */
  width:80%;
  height:60px;
  background:#hhh;
  opacity: 0.7;
  filter: alpha(opacity=70);
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

As you can see I am not shaping the body css but when I tried to do it I get the same result.

[image: Result of code]

Which in my opinion is too small in height. I used the image background-size: cover because it is what is recommended to make the background image responsive but it does not fit well.

My question is if it depends on the original size of the image or I am doing something wrong? and if there is any specific way to make the background really responsive? In other words to make the image background fit the maximum height and width of the screen of the the different mobile devices?

Answer (score 2):

You can try giving

```
#particles-js{
height:100vh;
}
```

Rather than giving it 100%,it will surely work.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is the way you are using height. You have set the height of #particles-js to 100%... but 100% of what? 
Try adding:

```
html{
 height:100%;
 min-height:100%;
 }
body{
 min-height:100%;
 }
```

Then add this:

```
background-image: image-url("rub.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Comment: I tried to do what you suggested but the same happened. The same result

Answer (score 0):

You have a few errors in your CSS, so maybe start by fixing them.

Line 19

```
background-image: image-url("rub.jpg");
```

to

```
background-image: url("rub.jpgf");
```

Line 25

```
background-position:cover;
```

syntax in invalid, correct values for the position are options like right top, or 50% 50%

Line 36 has an invalid color

```
  background:#hhh;
```

Comment: Line 19 is something used only in ruby on rails and it has to be done like that otherwise Heroku is not going to recognize the image.I took line 25 out so I dont have it anymore and I changed the color of line 36 thanks a lot for those observations. But the result is the same

Comment: my bad for line 19 ;) @jportella . If you could start a fully working example on Codepen.io or JSFiddle you'll make it easier for myself and others trying to help you